# Mockito pattern for a Spring web service call

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-ws

My class under test has this method

```
public SomeWebServiceResponse callDownstream(SomeWebServiceRequest request)  {
    return (SomeWebServiceResponse ) super.callService(request);
}
```

the super method is just a call to Spring WS to make the call - in simplified form

```
response = getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(this.getBaseURL(), 
    request);
return response;
```

When I write a unit test it tried to make an actual web service call. I'm not clear how to mock this or rather what we should be mocking.

Should I be loading a sample response from filesystem and looking for some string in it - in that case I'm only testing file loading.

The actual call is in base class and I know we can't mock only that method. Any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring does also provide facilities for mocking web service servers as well as requests from clients. The chapter 6.3 in the [Spring WS manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html#d5e1886) shows how to do mocking.

The Spring WS mocking facility changes the behaviour of the Web Service Template, so you can call that method in the super-class - that method would then call the Spring Mock Service Server.

Here is a sample unit test with the Spring mock service server:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring-ws.xml"})
public class SetStatusFromSrsTemplateTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockServer = MockWebServiceServer.createServer(wsTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCall() {
        SomeWebServiceRequest sampleRequest = new SomeWebServiceRequest();
        // add properties to the sampleRequest...
        Source expectedPayload = new ResourceSource(new ClassPathResource("exampleRequest.xml"));
        Source expectedResponse = new ResourceSource(new ClassPathResource("exampleResponse.xml"));
        mockServer.expect(payload(expectedPayload)).andRespond(withPayload(expectedResponse));
        instance.callDownStream(sampleRequest);
        mockServer.verify();
    }
}
```

The above example will make the mock service server expect exactly one request with the given payload and (if the payload received matches the expected payload) respond with the given response payload.

However, if you only want to verify that the method in the super-class is really called during the test and if you're not interested in the message exchange following that call, you should use Mockito.

If you'd like to use Mockito, I'd suggest the spy (see also Kamlesh's answer). E.g.

```
// Decorates this with the spy.
MyClass mySpy = spy(this);
// Change behaviour of callWebservice method to return specific response
doReturn(mockResponse).when(mySpy).callWebservice(any(SomeWebServiceRequest.class));
// invoke the method to be tested.
instance.callDownstream(request);
// verify that callWebService has been called
verify(mySpy, times(1)).callWebService(any(SomeWebServiceRequest.class));
```

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment's. I think I didn't quite understand the problem. I'll provide a sample how to make unit tests with Spring mock service server.

Comment: Mocking the whole web service including sending and receiving a message (first code example) is actually more than an unit test - it is an integration test as also pointed out by the referred Spring manual. If you just need an unit test then you should stick with Mockito (second code example).

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.AssertionError: Further connection(s) expected. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As @Duncan said composition with dependency injection would be a way to go if you can and then mock that dependency.

If you can't then you can selectively mock the methods of **class under test** using mockito [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html).